# EasySlider 1.7 - IE9 breaks it by blocking scripts

Tags: easyslider

I've been playing around with EasySlider and everything was working perfectly - until I viewed my site in IE9.

Instead of displaying the slider with 3 images sliding across, it displayed all 3 images sat one underneath the other, and a message at the bottom of the screen saying that scripts etc had been blocked and did I want to allow blocked content.

As I was using this in the hear of my website it pushed my whole site down the page and just looked stupid with the 3 banners on top of each other.

I realise I can get rid of this by unblocking the content, but that's not the point.  I think this is the default security settings for IE so everyone that visits my site will see it like this for the first time (or everytime if they don't unblock the content).

So is there a way around this?  Or at least a way that if the script is blocked only the first image is shown instead of all of them?  This seems a pretty big flaw!

Comment: Do you have doctype declared?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you and found a very simple solution for it using CSS. All you need to do is copy and paste the line of CSS code below onto the `screen.css` stylesheet that came with the EasySlider 1.7 Plugin. I hope this helps.

```
#slider {
    position:relative;
}
```

I found this solution at the ["ClickNathan Handmade Websites"](http://clicknathan.com/2011/04/04/easy-slider-1-7-with-internet-explorer-7-bug-fix/).